# Does $\sum_{k=0}^\infty t^{ak} $ converges if $0<t<1$ and $a>0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $t\in(0,1)$ and $a>0$. Does it holds that
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty t^{ak} <\infty?$$

If $a>1$, then each $t^{ak}<t^k$. And so $\sum_{k=0}^\infty t^{ak}<\sum_{k=0}^\infty t^{k}=\frac{1}{1-t}<\infty$. What if $0<a<1$?

Comment: Hint: $0<t^a<1$ and $t^{ak}=\left(t^a\right)^k.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$0<t<1$ and $a>0$ so $t^{a} < 1$. Hence,

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}t^{ak}={1 \over 1-t^a} < \infty$$

Comment: I think I need to rest a little bit...:D

Comment: Haha. We've all been there.